# How to get ouput of the sftp command for potential errors

Tags: shell, command-line, sftp

I connect to the sftp via command line like

```
sftp -P portnumber user@ip
```

then I run a command to upload a file via SFTP in the command-line interface. I used the following command

```
put file1.txt
```

This file is in several hundred GB. It stopped and failed.
Now I want to trigger the same command but to capture the output if any error happens and the process is stopped.
Is there any parameter or method that I can use to capture this with the above-mentioned command? i mean something like this

```
put file1.txt -o error or output
```

thanks

Comment: `script mysftp.log; sftp -vvv -P portnumber user@ip; exit; less mysftp.log` ?

Comment: the above command i should run when making a connection to the sftp?

Comment: @jhnc any hint or help would be greatly appreciated.